# Android: How to set time gap in methods, when sleep or wait is not working

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I built a TicTacToe game for android. And i want that there should be some time gap or time difference between User's turn and Computer's turn. Mean i want like a sleep() or any other method should be invoked between User's turn and Computer's turn. But when i call Sleep() before cpuPlay() method or after userPlay() it makes sleep to both user and Android and both wake up together. I really tried very hard to find why it is making sleep() to both method together but i am unable to find. Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.
Here's my code

```
public class Game extends Activity 
  {
private final int GAME_VICTORY = 0x1;
private final int GAME_DEFEAT = 0x2;
private final int GAME_TIE = 0x3;
private final int GAME_CONTINUES = 0x4;
private final float UNIQUE_MAX_WEIGHT=0.85f;
static final int ACTIVITY_SELECTION = 1;
private int x_Player_win_counter;
private int o_Player_win_counter;
public static TextView textlevel=null;
public static TextView textlevel1=null;
public double startTime;
double userDuration;
double cpuDuration;
private float[] w;  
private int[] c;        
private int[][] PosTable;   
private Button[] buttons;
private int lineH = -1;
private int lineV = -1;
private int lineD = -1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    buttons = new Button[9];

    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    buttons[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(0);
        }
    });
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    buttons[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(1);
        }
    });
    buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
    buttons[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(2);
        }
    });
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);
    buttons[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(3);
        }
    });
    buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button05);
    buttons[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(4);
        }
    });
    buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button06);
    buttons[5].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(5);
        }

    });
    buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07);
    buttons[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(6);
        }
    });
    buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button08);
    buttons[7].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(7);
        }
    });
    buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button09);
    buttons[8].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(8);
        }
    });

  startActivityForResult(new Intent(Game.this, Game.class), ACTIVITY_SELECTION);


    DisplayMetrics dm = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float h = (float) (dm.heightPixels - (100.0)*dm.density);
    float w = dm.widthPixels;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        buttons[i].setHeight((int) (h/3));
        buttons[i].setWidth((int) (w/3));
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    beginPlay();
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECTION) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras.getString("result").equals("CPU")) cpuPlay();
        }
    }
}
public void userGame() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("User Won!!!")
    .setMessage("want to start another game")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {

            buttonsEnable(true);
            beginPlay();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            finish();
        }
    })
    .show();        
}

public void cpuGame() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Android Won!!!")
    .setMessage("want to start another game")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {

            buttonsEnable(true);
            beginPlay();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            finish();
        }
    })
    .show();
}

public void tieGame() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("TIE!!!")
    .setMessage("want to start another game")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {

            buttonsEnable(true);
            beginPlay();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            finish();
        }
    })
    .show();
}


private void beginPlay() {
    //initializations start 
    w=new float[9];
    c=new int[9];
    InitTable();
    w[0]=0.7f;
    w[1]=0.4f;
    w[2]=0.7f;
    w[3]=0.4f;
    w[4]=0.7f;
    w[5]=0.4f;
    w[6]=0.7f;
    w[7]=0.4f;
    w[8]=0.7f;
    //c[i] : 0 for empty, 1 for cpu, 2 for user
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        c[i]=0;
    //initializations done

    //now we play!


        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        textlevel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.userInfo);
        textlevel.setText(String.valueOf(x_Player_win_counter));

        textlevel1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cpuInfo);
        textlevel1.setText(String.valueOf(o_Player_win_counter));

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {     
        updateBtn(i);
        buttons[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    String PlayerName="User";       
    updateGameInfo(PlayerName + " turn.");
}

private void cpuPlay() 
{
    int cpos=getDecision();
    if (cpos == -1) 
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GAME OVER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    } 
    else
    {
    c[cpos]=1;
    updateBtn(cpos);
    String name= "user";
    updateGameInfo(name + " turn");
    int gstatus = CheckGameStatus();
    if (gstatus == GAME_VICTORY) 
    {
        userDuration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrts You Won in " + userDuration + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        ++x_Player_win_counter;
        userGame();
    }
    else if (gstatus == GAME_DEFEAT) {
        cpuDuration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Android Won in "  + cpuDuration + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        ++o_Player_win_counter;
        cpuGame();
    }
    else if (gstatus == GAME_TIE) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Its a TIE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        tieGame();
    }
    else if (gstatus == GAME_CONTINUES) {
        //user plays
    }
    }
}
private void updateBtn(int i) {
    if(c[i]==0)
    {   
        buttons[i].setText(" ");        
    }
    else if(c[i]==1)
    {

        buttons[i].setText("O");
        buttons[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else
    {
        buttons[i].setText("X");            
    }
}

private int CheckGameStatus() {
    int s = 0;
    //check horizontal
    if(c[0]==2&&c[1]==2&&c[2]==2) 
    {
        s = GAME_VICTORY;           
    }
    if(c[3]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[5]==2) 
    {
        s = GAME_VICTORY;           
    }
    if(c[6]==2&&c[7]==2&&c[8]==2) 
    {
        s = GAME_VICTORY;           
    }
    if(c[0]==1&&c[1]==1&&c[2]==1) 
    {
        s = GAME_DEFEAT;            
    }
    if(c[3]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[5]==1) 
    {
        s = GAME_DEFEAT;            
    }
    if(c[6]==1&&c[7]==1&&c[8]==1) 
    {
        s = GAME_DEFEAT;            
    }
    //check vertical
    if(c[0]==2&&c[3]==2&&c[6]==2) 
    {
        s = GAME_VICTORY;           
    }
    if(c[1]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[7]==2) 
    {
        s = GAME_VICTORY;           
    }
    if(c[2]==2&&c[5]==2&&c[8]==2) 
    {
        s = GAME_VICTORY;           
    }
    if(c[0]==1&&c[3]==1&&c[6]==1) 
    {
        s = GAME_DEFEAT;            
    }
    if(c[1]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[7]==1) 
    {
        s = GAME_DEFEAT;
    }
    if(c[2]==1&&c[5]==1&&c[8]==1) 
    {
        s = GAME_DEFEAT;
    }
    //check diagonal
    if(c[0]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[8]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[2]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[6]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[0]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[8]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[2]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[6]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}

    if (s != 0) {
        buttonsEnable(false);
        return s;
    }

    boolean box_empty = false;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if (c[i] == 0) box_empty = true;
    }
    if (box_empty) {    //if any box is empty -> game continues
        return GAME_CONTINUES;
    }
    else {  //else there is tie
        buttonsEnable(false);
        return GAME_TIE;
    }
}

private void buttonsEnable(boolean b) {
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        buttons[i].setEnabled(b);
}

private void btnClicked(int i)
{   
    if(c[i]!=0) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position occupied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    else 
    {
        //all OK
        c[i] = 2;
        updateBtn(i);       
        String name= "Android";
    //  updateGameInfo(name + " turn");

        int gstatus = CheckGameStatus();
        if (gstatus == GAME_VICTORY) {
            userDuration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrats You Won in "  + userDuration + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            ++x_Player_win_counter;
            userGame();
        }
        else if (gstatus == GAME_DEFEAT) {
            cpuDuration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Android Won in "  + cpuDuration + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            ++o_Player_win_counter;
            cpuGame();
        }
        else if (gstatus == GAME_TIE) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Its a TIE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            tieGame();
        }
        else if (gstatus == GAME_CONTINUES) {   
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cpuPlay();
        }
    }
}

private int getDecision() 
{   
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++) {
            if(c[i]==1&&c[j]==1)    //place 'o' to win
                if(PosTable[i][j]!=-1)  //if we have 3 in a row
                    if(c[PosTable[i][j]]==0)    //if position is free
                        return PosTable[i][j];
            if(c[i]==2&&c[j]==2)    //place 'o' to prevent user's victory
                if(PosTable[i][j]!=-1)  //if we have 3 in a row
                    if(c[PosTable[i][j]]==0)    //if position is free
                        return PosTable[i][j];
        }

    if(c[0]==1&&c[8]==0) return 8;
    if(c[2]==1&&c[6]==0) return 6;
    if(c[8]==1&&c[0]==0) return 0;
    if(c[6]==1&&c[2]==0) return 2;
    Random r=new Random();
    boolean exist07=false;
    boolean[] free=new boolean[9]; //will hold the free positions
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        free[i]=false;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        if(c[i]==0) {   //free ??
            free[i]=true;   //add position to free
            if(w[i]==UNIQUE_MAX_WEIGHT) return i;
        }
    //more than 1 positions with same weight
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        if(free[i]) //if position is free
            if(w[i]==0.7f) exist07=true;
    if(exist07)
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            if(free[i]) //if position is free
                if(w[i]==0.4f) free[i]=false;

    int j=0;
    int rn=0;
    int[] tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        if(free[i]) j++;
    if(j!=0) {
        tmp=new int[j];
        rn=r.nextInt(j);
        j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            if(free[i]) tmp[j++]=i;
        return tmp[rn];
    }
    else {
        return -1; //else GAME OVER
    }
}
private void InitTable() {

    PosTable=new int[9][9];
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
            PosTable[i][j]=-1;
    PosTable[0][1]=2;
    PosTable[0][2]=1;
    PosTable[0][3]=6;
    PosTable[0][4]=8;
    PosTable[0][6]=3;
    PosTable[0][8]=4;
    PosTable[1][2]=0;
    PosTable[1][4]=7;
    PosTable[1][7]=4;
    PosTable[2][4]=6;
    PosTable[2][5]=8;
    PosTable[2][6]=4;
    PosTable[2][8]=5;
    PosTable[3][4]=5;
    PosTable[3][5]=4;
    PosTable[3][6]=0;
    PosTable[4][5]=3;
    PosTable[4][6]=2;
    PosTable[4][7]=1;
    PosTable[4][8]=0;
    PosTable[5][8]=2;
    PosTable[6][7]=8;
    PosTable[6][8]=7;
    PosTable[7][8]=6;
}

private void updateGameInfo(String info)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    TextView infoView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameInfo);
    infoView.setText(info);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to delay some code, you should post it in a handler with a delay time.
This way the handler will wait the given time and then execute the given runnable.

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            cpuPlay();
        }
    }, TIME_TO_WAIT_IN_MS);
```

Answer (score 1):

use Handler. if you want example of code here it is.

```
Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        cpuPlay();
    }
}, TIME_TO_WAIT_IN_MS);`
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because both method are running by same thread so sleep() won't work here. You have to use Handler whereever you want to wait your system

Answer (score 0):

If you do a Thread.sleep in the UI Thread, you sleep the main thread, so you need to do your sleep in a thread or use a handler or an AsyncTask.

Comment: hey i tried to do that also but didn't get it so can u elaborate it please.